# Jenkins distributed building configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm trying to build a software project in 4 different configurations: 32bit-debug, 32bit-release, 64bit-debug, 64bit-debug on a Windows 7 machine.  Our setup currently involves the master (0 executors), and 2 slaves each with 2 executors.  One slave is a Mac the other is a Windows machine--I'm currently just trying to build on Windows.

My configuration matrix is setup like this:

- 1st Axis: User-defined Axis, Name: Architecture, Values: 32bit, 64bit
- 2nd Axis: Slaves, Name: OS, I selected the node that represents the Windows machine
- 3rd Axis: User-defined Axis, Name: BuildType, Values: debug, release

The matrix...

```
+----------------------+-------+--------+
| Configuration Matrix | 32bit | 64-bit |
+----------------------+-------+--------+
| Debug                |   X   |    X   |
+----------------------+-------+--------+
| Release              |   X   |    X   |
+----------------------+-------+--------+
```

It is able to successfully check out the source code from Git into all 4 build folders in the workspace.  However, while defining the build step is where I get lost.  I select "Execute Windows batch command."  This is where I become lost...what to I specify in the box so it knows which batch file to call based on which of the 4 builds it is?

I assume it is related to Jenkin's environment variables, but I envision doing something like:

```
if (Windows Slave Machine)
{
    if (Architecture == 32bit)
    {
        if (BuildType == debug)
        {
            //Call win_32bit_debug.bat
        }
        else
        {
            //Call win_32bit_release.bat
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (BuildType == debug)
        {
            //Call win_64bit_debug.bat
        }
        else
        {
            //Call win_64bit_release.bat
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just create 4 jobs which call different batch files? Cramming all this into a single job seems needlessly complex.

Comment: I understand.  But I feel that maintaining separate jobs (especially because this scales up to 24 configurations) will be unwieldy especially because all the settings are the same except for which batch file gets executed.

Comment: Do you went this to be used via a CI model where it runs after each commit, or is this a manual job which would be run by a user?

Comment: It will be fired by Gerrit on a new patchset, so yes, after every commit.

Comment: So how are you defining what should be built based on a given commit? Seems like you should be building everything....

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write this log if-statement inside the "Execute Windows batch command."
Just try to make use of the variables you have already defined like that:

```
win_%Architecture%_%BuildType%.bat
```